# How do I configure a server to stop blocking unzipped files

Tags: windows-server-2008, security

I have an application running on Windows2008 server. The automated deployment process drops a zipped package onto a folder, and then another script unzips this and copies the executables.

The problem is, the executables are blocked from running, and I have to unblock them explicitly.

Is there some setting on the server which can stop this happening?

I want to the server to allow unzipped executables to run automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this question here: http://www.petri.co.il/unblock-files-windows-vista.htm

It's an interesting page, but the specific steps I gleaned from this are:

- In the Run box or console window type:
  GPEDIT.MSC to bring up the Group
  Policy Object editor.
- Navigate to User Configuration >
  Administrative Templates > Windows
  Components > Attachment Manager.
- ENABLE the policy called "Do not preserve
  zone information in file
  attachments".